# Best approach for a UICollectionView to look like the iOS calendar app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm building an app where I really need to display a list like the one seen in the iOS calendar app. I need to create a collectionView where I can have cells that expand enough to cover their respective hours, like so:

[image]

I've tried various things, including [this project](https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout) at Github which I didn't understand how to use in another project

As well as this project I quickly made with a UITableViewController while exploring different methods:

[image]

But I'm not really getting where I want to. I need to have the design seen in the first picture and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to achieve that?

Thank you so much for help!!

**Update:**

Shouldn't the actual cell frame represent the start of an hour, 10:00 in this example? (Rather than the custom-made separator)

[image]

**Update**

Why does the hierarchy look like this:

[image]

This kind of positioning appears to be "blocking" the touch of the cells and the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method doesn't get called. This applies to the cells that appear further back than the other ones.

[image]

Comment: Is that view meant to only display stuff or does the user need to grab and edit events?
If it's just displaying and selecting for details then it shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: @Zil just displaying and pressing an event to segue to a detail viewController

Comment: Now that I've tried to write down an answer it's acutally more complicated than anticipated :D

Comment: The  github project looks pretty decent, if not better. What's causing you trouble with it exactly? Importing it or creating the collectionview?

Comment: I really don't understand it at all, I haven't dealt with navigation without StoryBoards before and I'm having a hard time separating the different parts of the project and getting that overview to understand it. Can't find any tutorial or approach to use it :P I have to integrate it into a fairly big StoryBoard and logic of my app so I need to understand it first

Comment: Well considering he's got all the job done if I were you I would focus on trying to implement his work instead of trying to re-do it from scratch. He links examples and projects using his code in the description and in the github files, I think you should try to read and understand that and make up your implementation out of it. Either way this task is gonna take you a long time, so better out having a result like his view instead of the one you've shown in the sreenshot :P

Comment: Yeah :P agree on that one. Have you downloaded his project? I see he's not using Storyboard but how is he opening the ViewController? Something in the AppDelegate?

Comment: I'm not on a reliable compuer and I'm not gonna lie, I'm too tired (1am) to check now... Ring me back here tomorrow and i'll have a look

Comment: Of course, no problem. It's 1am here too so I'm checking out for the day. We'll continue tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @Zil hello again! Do you have some time today to check out that github project?

Comment: Spend more time on using the [MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout](https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout) which you have mentioned in your question. It has exactly what you need. You are spending too much time in reinventing what the GitHub project already does.

Comment: @lukya I'm having a lot of difficulties even understanding the project. I feel they've added so much unnecessary, and I'm far from certain as to where I'm even going to begin

Comment: The GitHub download probably includes the core code as well as demo/example app which you can refer but not really need.. However, the wiki mentions installation using CocoaPods.. which is a one line install.. which should directly integrate the component in your app. If you are not familiar with CocoaPods, [learning CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) will be pretty quick and really worth it.

Comment: @lukya I see. I've set up a test project and successfully installed the MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout pod. The workspace builds and works. I've read the wiki over at cocoapods.org and see a variety of properties but I'm not quite sure where to continue - could you please explain? It's helping me a lot!

Comment: Once installation with CocoaPods is done, for now, you need not get into more details of CocoaPods. Just start using the classes in your own code directly.

Comment: Yeah I understand, but the library seems quite advanced and that's really what I need help to. I understand if you don't have to do a large explanation but if you could kick me off in the right direction and how to implement his library then that would be really nice:) meanwhile I'm checking out the ViewController implementation file in his example project

Comment: @lukya I've taken a look into the ViewController and seems like MSEvent.h is the only class it can't import but I've got my own "MSEvent". The ViewController files has some methods and functions I'm more familiar with so I'm probably getting a fully functional project today. Your answer will highly likely but the one to get 50 reputation, so if you create an answer that would be great :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76914/discussion-between-erik-and-lukya).

Comment: @lukya hello again! I'm in the chat room whenever (if of course) you have time!:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should indeed use a `UICollectionView` along with a custom layout.  Just provide `supplementary views` to build the underlying daily schedule (one view per hour), and then use the `cells` to lay down your events.

When subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout`, you need to implement a few methods:

- `collectionViewContentSize` should return a height equal to the number of hours (24) multiplied by the height of a supplementary view representing an hour.
- `prepareLayout` does almost everything.  In that method, you calculate every *layoutAttributes* you will need to use.  By getting the time of the event and its duration, you are able to compute the frame of every event.  The supplementary view frames (every single "hour" block) are pretty straightforward too, since their height is fixed (origin.y = fixed height multiplied by the hour).
- `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` simply iterates through your previously prepared *layoutAttributes* and returns all whose frame intersect the provided frame.
- `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` finds and returns the cell's *layoutAttributes* that match the provided indexPath.
- `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:atIndexPath` finds and returns the supplementary view's *layoutAttributes* that math the provided indexPath.

Next, you give an instance of that layout to a collection view:

```
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:myCustomLayout]
```

Then, you only need to provide the required views for the supplementary views (a.k.a the hour blocks) and the cells, via the UICollectionView's delegate & dataSource.  Feel free to create a custom delegate in your custom layout if you need the UIViewController to provide more info that you have with the standard delegate/dataSource!

*Note:* Since the line that indicate the start of an hour is a few pixels below the cell's top border, you need to shift every time of event by the same number of pixels.  Say you have 6 pixels above every line and every hour block has a height of 60 pixels, then if an even start at 2AM, you will set its `origin.y = 2 * 60 + 6` (2 hours * 60 pixels per hour + 6 pixels padding).  You will also need to adjust you last cell block to be 6 pixels taller since it won't have another cell below.

I recommend you to read [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html) about creating custom layouts.

**To help you:** I made a [quick sample project](https://github.com/simondec/sample-calendar) since making your own layout can sometime be troublesome.  Go check the `CalendarViewLayout` class, I added a few comments to explain how I dealt with the padding.  Here is was it looks like:

[image: Sample]

Comment: Very thoroughly completed answer and very helpful!

Comment: I'm trying to add a line displaying the current time but I'm not quite how to accomplish it. I looked at the HourReusableView class and tried to make a similar one but can't make it work. Could you help?

Comment: @Erik I will help but I can't right now, I will have time by Sunday or Monday.

Comment: No problem:) whenever you got time

Comment: Hello again, do you think you have some time to look at this today?:)

Comment: Hello again! Not meaning to push you, but do you think you could help me take a look this today? :) I'm sure we can implement it pretty fast

Comment: Hey!  Sorry, been hard at work lately.  Having a simple line would be as simple as creating another subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` that would display a line (the view itself could be 1 pixel high, or contains a subview of 1 pixel high).  Register that new cell, and use section index = 1 for that view.  Update your layout class to handle that cell specifically (`if (indexPath.section == 1) {}`), and add a delegate method to get the current time (a NSInteger).  Add a timer in your viewController that ask the collectionView to reload that specific cell every minutes.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that asap tomorrow! Thanks for the help, really great you took the time - helps me a lot :)

Comment: tried that now but I don't quite see the connection between all the functions and methods yet to pull this off

Comment: Hey! Please take a look at my question update. Your project works fantastic apart from when I can't select rows. Could you please help me solve this? Xcode's visual debugger might give us a hint of what is happening

Comment: Hi @Erik!  We are using `UICollectionReusableView` as "decoration views" to display the hours grid, and as such they don't trigger the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` callback because they aren't cells.  You would get that callback by tapping on an event displayed over the grid (whose are laid out using cells) .  To mimic the native iOS app, I would add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the collection view, and use that gesture to prompt a "new event" view.  I would then use the gesture's position to get an appropriate default value for the "start time".

Comment: Yeah, I understand - also had a problem with the cells not calling `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, but that got resolved. Good idea with the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is so hard to do.

You just need a different perspective, than what you tried.

Make all the CollectionView cells the same size. They represent 1h time, so they should have equal size.

Then have another view in each cell. This is the one that show that there is an event. This view you will give a color, and place it in the cell according to the time when the event start or finish.
So in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, you would check your events and if this cell have any event then you are going to show this event view, color it, and position it. If you make the cells height 60, it gets super easy to position the view. For example if the event start at 1:20, at the cell for hour 1, you will size the event view (0, 20, 320, 40).

Comment: I thought of doing this, but there is a slight problem to it. I need to have the time labels at the left, with the tableView separator in the middle, and then the separator which represents for instance 07:00 won't be at the (0,0) coordinates

Comment: Don't use the tableView separator at all. Just use a view with height 1 and show or hide or position it as you need.

Comment: Yeah that is completely fine. But if I set a cell to represent one hour, and I need a label right next to the said separator (custom), then half of that label is going to be outside the cell or the custom made separator won't be representing the start of the hour. See my update for some clarification

Comment: I don't see how that is a problem. Yes, you have a separator. Yes it's positioned 10 pixels down the cell. You still have the same distance to represent 1h between the separator for 12:00 and the separator for 1:00 for example.

Comment: true. I'll see what I can do! Do you recommend using a CollectionView or tableView for this?

Comment: I don't know all the details of you app, but it's easier with tableView. Easier but a lot less options too. For example if you ever want to have horizontal scroll you need a collection. I would say use a tableView if it provides all that you need. If you find that you want to do something and you can't, change it to a CollectionView. It's not that hard to switch from one to another.

Comment: I agree with using tableView, I'll start with that and see where that takes me

Answer (score 1):

As per discussion in comments on the question, using the [Custom Collection View Layout library](https://github.com/erichoracek/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout) linked in the question is suitable for the mentioned problem which can be easily integrated using [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html).

UICollectionView is highly customizable using custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. See the official apple documentation for [creating custom layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html).

To be frank, Apple's documentation is too overwhelming for most of us. So, you can look up (google) [*custom UICollectionViewLayout tutorial*](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gaZHVer-N8v08wfe4YD4Cg&gws_rd=ssl#q=custom+UICollectionViewLayout+tutorial), go through any one you find the easiest and go on to use the library to your specific needs.