# Can't tap UICollectionView item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm building an app whereas I've got a `UICollectionView` with a custom layout. I have a problem whereas I cannot tap some rows. Here's an overview over what happens

1) App starts and presents a `UICollectionView`

2) 3 test items are displayed, using the visual debugger in Xcode, you can see that there is something not right with the hierarchy

[image]

**The red row can't be tapped now, but the yellow and green rows can.**

3) User taps the yellow item, and segues to another page

4) User pops the shown `UIViewController` and returns to the `UICollectionView` whereas the `viewWillAppear` method reloads the `UICollectionView` like so:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

5) Re-entering the visual debugger shows that the hierarchy seems shifted, and the yellow row is now untappable, but the red and green rows can be tapped.

**What could be the reason for this?** I'll post any relevant code, ask for what parts you'd like to see.

[image]

**Update**

The `UIViewController` displaying the `UICollectionView`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
ShareViewCell *view = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"share" forIndexPath:indexPath];
view.share = [self.sharesController shareAtIndex:indexPath.item];
return view;
}
```

Custom cell:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

    self.leftBorderView = [UIView new];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.leftBorderView];

    self.label = [UILabel new];
    self.label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.label];
}
return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

self.leftBorderView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1.5, self.bounds.size.height);
CGSize labelSize = [self.label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width - 10.0f, MAXFLOAT)];

NSTimeInterval durationOfShare = [self.share.endSpan timeIntervalSinceDate:self.share.startSpan] / 3600;

CGFloat middleOfCell = self.bounds.size.height / 2;
CGFloat yPositionToUse = middleOfCell - (labelSize.height / 2);

if (durationOfShare < 0.25)
{
    [self.label setHidden:YES];// to small to be shown
} else if (durationOfShare > 0.5)
{
    yPositionToUse = 8; // show it at the top
}

self.label.frame = CGRectMake(8, yPositionToUse, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);
}
```

**Update 2**

Is the `UICollectionReusableView` blocking tap of the `UICollectionViewCell`?

[image]

Comment: How you define view for each item in UICollectionView? If in storyboard check whether all views have set userInteraction enabled and check layout constraints. 
If programmatically post any code when defining the view.

Comment: @TomasCejka added some code that lays out the cell, do you want code from the custom layout as well? Everything is done in code

Comment: can't tap only some rows ? Did u add any tao gestures/swipe gestures ?

Comment: @Mr.T Yeah, and those rows change as shown in the two pictures. First, I can't tap the red row, but next time after `reloadData`, I can't tap the yellow row. The untappable rows change as to which row I select. Haven't added any gestures

Comment: did u try reloading them in view did appear?

Comment: is the yellow,red green items are uilabels ?

Comment: @Mr.T They're subclasses of `UICollectionViewCell`. Tried that, yes - same behaviour

Comment: so when u tap on red item , did select item is not called . is that what you say ?

Comment: check the content view size/label size in that cell where u don't get tap. If the size is less than collection cell, you don't get any taps.

Comment: also try to call [self setneedsdisplay] after u change the frame in the layoutsubviews method!!!

Comment: looks like the sizes are correct, and `setNeedsDisplay` didn't change the haviour. Take a look at the images again, it looks like the `UICollectionReusableView` is laid on top of the cell, hence "blocking" the tap

Comment: Have you made any changes to  `UICollectionView`'s `allowsSelection` or `allowsMultipleSelection`?

Comment: @adrianokw I haven't made any changes to those, no

Comment: Do you set the cell as selected?

Comment: Try if code go throught initWithFrame and try code move to awakeFromNib - if you use storyboard you should use this method. Then check sizes in layoutSubviews and whether you checked autoresize cell by content. Check each cell size. I cant help more I'm away my mac

Comment: @adrianokw the cells do not appear to be set as selected

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the addsubview methods in your custom cell's initWithFrame? What happens when you dont customize the cell?

Comment: @ozgur Just tried now, exact same behaviour

Comment: Wow... Why don't you use constraints to define your layout ? Overriding 'layoutSubviews', seems quite confusing... Have you tried commenting lines that set frames (I would comment the last one... `self.label.frame = xxx`). But hard to tell without your code, it might not be related to your cells at all. Do you have section header or footer views ?

Comment: @Vinzzz this part of my project is a customized version of the project linked in the answer from Rufel in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927088/best-approach-for-a-uicollectionview-to-look-like-the-ios-calendar-app), which, after I downloaded it again and did some testing, appear to have just the same problem - so you could download it and see yourself in the Xcode visual debugger. In the meantime,(if you decide to test it) I'll test your idea

Comment: @Vinzzz didn't make a difference to comment out that label. I don't have header or footer views, no

Comment: Lol, you say... But you pointed me on a project code - which mimic a calendar interface using `UICollectionView` with supplementaryView `HourReusableView`.

Comment: @Vinzzz can't tell exactly what you mean here. The project isn't same as mine, but it demonstrates the same problem

Comment: Is it the same or not... See my proposed answer !

Comment: @Vinzzz it's not the same. It's built using code from the project I linked to, but heavily modified. I'm only using it as an example because the sample problem exists in both projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

First, you should be more precise in your question : you're using some code found on [some question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927088/best-approach-for-a-uicollectionview-to-look-like-the-ios-calendar-app).

The code seems to be this [Calendar UI made with UICollectionView](https://github.com/simondec/sample-calendar).
This is a sample code, quickly built for the sake of a StackOverflow answer (with a bounty). It's not finished, has no contributors, and you should try to read it and improve over it !

From your debugger's captures, it seems you have some view which overlays on top of your collectionView's cells.
From reading this code, I see it uses some supplementary view to present 'hour' blocks. This supplementary view class is `HourReusableView`. And it's the view coming on top on your debugger's captures

`CalendarViewLayout` is responsible to compute these supplementary views frame, as it does for colored event blocks (see method `- (void)prepareLayout`)

I might bet that these supplementary views's Z-order isn't predictable - all views have a default zIndex of 0. One way to fix it ? After [line 67 of this file](https://github.com/simondec/sample-calendar/blob/master/sample-calendar/UI/CalendarViewLayout.m), set a negative `zIndex` on the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` of the hour block. This way, you make sure hour supplementary views are always behind your cells, and don't intercept the cell's touch

Comment: Seems very logical. I did this and added `attributes.zIndex = -1;` just after line 75 in the file you linked to, which made the visual debugger display a correct hierarchy in Xcode and the problem is now gone. I'll definitely improve over this part of the app further though. I'll also award the bounty asap I can, which isn't before 22 hours has passed from now. Thank you!